# Android class getter with selection

Tags: android, class

I want to create a method in a class that returns the object of the class where the property is equal to a certain value:

```
public class Category {

private String name;
private String baseUnit;


public Category() {   
}

public Category(String name, String baseUnit) {
    this.name = name;
    this.baseUnit = baseUnit;
}

public Category getCategoryByName (String name) {
    ...............
    return category;
}
```

So I want to return a category object with the getCategoryByName(String name) method utilizing the parameter "name" to select the right one.

Let's say I have a list of Categories:

```
Category category1 = new Category("Weight", "kgs")
Category category2 = new Category("Height", "meters")
```

I have a category name "Weight" but I don't know it's baseUnit, so I want to retrieve the Category object that belong with the name "Weight".

Comment: The question in this post is very hard to discern. Please consider revising to receive better answers

Comment: "select the right one", what does this mean? Please clarify.

Comment: I think it's pretty straightforward what I want to be able to do, no? I just want a method in the class Category that will give me the Category object where it's name is "...".

Comment: Just say search. What you describe is search.

Answer (score 0):

```
private List<String> categoryNames;
private List<Category> categories;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(String name : categoryNames) {
        System.out.println(getCategoryByName(name)).getName();
    }
}

public Category getCategoryByName(String name) {
    for (Category category : categories) {
        if (category.getName().equals(name)) {
            return category;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Can you try to write it out because I'm not 100% sure what you're saying. I can't use a setter because I have no category object.

Can I instead write this code in my activity where I have 2 lists: List<String>categoryNamesList and List<Category>categoriesList?

Let's say a user selects a name from the first list, how can I get the Category object out of categoriesList that has that name?